# Custom CacheResolver not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

I have a Spring Boot project with a custom `CacheResolver` as I need to decide on runtime which cache I want to use, I don't have any compilation errors but, when I do some tests and place a break point at my custom `CacheResolver` it never steps into it.

This is my Configuration class for the Cache:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching(proxyTargetClass = true)
@PropertySource(CacheConfig.CLASSPATH_DEPLOY_CACHE_PROPERTIES_PROPERTIES)
public class CacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport{

      public static final String CLASSPATH_DEPLOY_CACHE_PROPERTIES_PROPERTIES = "classpath:/deploy/cache-properties.properties";

      public static final String CACHEABLE_DOCUMENTS_PROPERTY = "cacheable.documents";
      public static final String TTL_CACHEABLE_DOCUMENTS_PROPERTY = "ttl.cacheable.documents";
      public static final String SIZED_CACHEABLE_DOCUMENTS_PROPERTY = "sized.cacheable.documents";
      public static final String CACHE_NAME = "permanentCache";
      public static final String TTL_CACHE = "ttlCache";
      public static final String SIZED_CACHE = "sizedCache";
      public static final String CACHEABLE_DOCUMENTS = "cacheableDocuments";
      public static final String SIZED_CACHEABLE_DOCUMENTS = "sizedCacheableDocuments";
      public static final int WEIGHT = 1000000;
      public static final int TO_KBYTES = 1000;

      @Inject
      protected Environment environment;

      //@Bean
      @Override
      public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        GuavaCache sizedCache = new GuavaCache(SIZED_CACHE, CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumWeight(WEIGHT).weigher(
                (key, storable) -> {
                  String json = ((Storable) storable).toJson();
                  return json.getBytes().length / TO_KBYTES;
                }
        ).build());
        GuavaCache permanentCache = new GuavaCache(CACHE_NAME,CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build());
        //GuavaCache ttlCache = new GuavaCache(TTL_CACHE, CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build());
        cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(permanentCache,sizedCache));
        return cacheManager;
      }

      @Bean(name = "wgstCacheResolver")
      @Override
      public CacheResolver cacheResolver(){
        CacheResolver cacheResolver = new WgstCacheResolver(cacheManager(),cacheableDocuments(),sizedCacheableDocuments());
        return cacheResolver;
      }


      @Bean(name = CACHEABLE_DOCUMENTS)
      public List<String> cacheableDocuments(){
        String[] cacheableDocuments = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray(environment.getProperty(CACHEABLE_DOCUMENTS_PROPERTY));
        return Arrays.asList(cacheableDocuments);
      }

      @Bean(name = SIZED_CACHEABLE_DOCUMENTS)
      public List<String> sizedCacheableDocuments(){
        String[] sizedCacheableDocuments = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray(environment.getProperty(SIZED_CACHEABLE_DOCUMENTS_PROPERTY));
        return Arrays.asList(sizedCacheableDocuments);
      } 
    }
```

Here is my CacheResolver

```
public class WgstCacheResolver extends AbstractCacheResolver {

  private final List<String> cacheableDocuments;
  private final List<String> sizedCacheableDocuments;

  public WgstCacheResolver(final CacheManager cacheManager,final List<String> cacheableDocuments, final List<String> sizedCacheableDocuments) {
    super(cacheManager);
    this.cacheableDocuments = cacheableDocuments;
    this.sizedCacheableDocuments = sizedCacheableDocuments;
  }

  /**
   * Resolves the cache(s) to be updated on runtime
   * @param context
   * @return*/
  @Override
  protected Collection<String> getCacheNames(final CacheOperationInvocationContext<?> context) {

    final Collection<String> cacheNames = new ArrayList<>();
    final AbstractDao dao = (AbstractDao)context.getTarget();
    final String documentType = dao.getDocumentType().toString();
    if (cacheableDocuments.contains(documentType)){
      cacheNames.add("permanentCache");
    }
    if (sizedCacheableDocuments.contains(documentType)){
      cacheNames.add("sizedCache");
    }
    return cacheNames;
  }
}
```

And here my DAO where I use the cache:

```
    @Component
    @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.DEFAULT)
    @CacheConfig(cacheResolver = "wgstCacheResolver")
    public class CacheableDao<T extends Storable> extends AbstractDao<T> {

      private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CacheableDao.class);

      public CacheableDao(final Bucket bucket, final Class<T> typeParameterClass, final DocumentType documentType) {
        super(bucket, typeParameterClass, documentType);
      }

      @Cacheable(key = "{#root.methodName, #root.target.generateFullKey(#key)}")
      public T get(final String key) throws DatastoreAccessException, ObjectMappingException {
        //do something
      }
.
.
.
}
```

I have tried implementing `CacheResolver` instead of extending `AbstractCacheResolver` but it didn't make any difference.

Thank you.

Comment: Well you don't have any cache name there so if caching works, it must resolve the cache name otherwise it will throw an exception. My best guess is that caching does not work at all. Your configuration is also very _weird_. You use `CachingConfiguration` to provide the _default_ `CacheResolver` so you don't need to specify it at all. If you want to specify it per operation (with a special name), define it elsewhere (not as the default).

Comment: Thank you @stéphane-nicoll , you pointed me in the right direction, I fixed the problem by including the available cache names with the `CacheConfig` annotation, ran my tests and debugged and now the custom `CacheResolver` is working as expected. I assumed that cache names wouldn't need to be included as the `CacheResolver` was there.

Comment: You're welcome but the cache names are not needed. Like I said, if your cache resolver was not called and you had no exception, you probably had no caching at all. That answer below is incorrect (unless there is a bug)

Comment: If I don't include the cache names I get a `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No cache names could be detected on 'public net.wgst.server.publicapi.documents.Storable net.wgst.server.test.config.testclasses.CacheableDaoForTesting.get(java.lang.String) throws net.wgst.server.api.exceptions.DatastoreAccessException,net.wgst.server.publicapi.exceptions.ObjectMappingException'. Make sure to set the value parameter on the annotation or declare a @CacheConfig at the class-level with the default cache name(s) to use.`

Comment: Well either you don't have a `CacheResolver` then or you have one and it returned an empty list. Can you share a project that exhibits this? Maybe there's a bug after all. If you have a ` CacheResolver` for the method you do not need to specify any cache names at all. My best guess is that your CacheResolver returns an empty list.

Comment: I have created a small project where I reproduce the issue, you can find it here https://github.com/tommylii/spring-cache/

Answer (score 2):

Cache names need to be included at some point, just specifying the `CacheResolver` to use is not enough, the `@Cacheable` class needs to be aware of the available cache names, so I included them with the `@CacheConfig` annotation:

```
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = {WgstCacheConfig.PERMANENT_CACHE, WgstCacheConfig.SIZED_CACHE},
    cacheResolver = WgstCacheConfig.WGST_CACHE_RESOLVER)
public class CacheableDao<T extends Storable> extends AbstractDao<T> {
```

One thing that I don't like is that I need to provide a null `CacheManager`, even if I'm not using it, otherwise I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No CacheResolver specified, and no bean of type CacheManager found. Register a CacheManager bean or remove the @EnableCaching annotation from your configuration.
```

So I left it like this, and it works:

```
  @Bean
  public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    return null;
  }

  @Bean(name = WGST_CACHE_RESOLVER)
  public CacheResolver cacheResolver(){
    CacheResolver cacheResolver = new WgstCacheResolver(cacheableDocuments(),sizedCacheableDocuments(),getPermanentCache(),
                                                        getSizedCache());
    return cacheResolver;
  }
```

Reran my tests, stepping through my custom `CacheResolver` and it is behaving as expected resolving to the correct cache(s)

My configuration class is not extending `CachingConfigurerSupport` anymore.

Comment: How're you able to get by with a null `CacheManager` in `WgstCacheResolver` when the superclass `AbstractCacheResolver` has an explicit check for it in the `afterPropertiesSet` method?
`public void afterPropertiesSet()  {`
     `Assert.notNull(this.cacheManager, "CacheManager must not be null");`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of back and forth (Sorry about that!) it turns out this is indeed a bug in Spring Framework.

I've created [SPR-13081](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13081). Expect a fix for the next maintenance release (`4.1.7.RELEASE`). Thanks for the sample project!

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to configure a global cache without having to specify a name on every method or class. I understand that a custom `CacheResolver` could be provided instead of a name. What is not clear from the docs is if the method/class still has to refer to it in the annotation or do you look it up by type if none is specified?

Comment: If you specify a custom cache resolver that's what we're going to invoke when we need to resolve the cache names. How the appropriate cache(s) are resolved is completely up to your implementation. Having said that, I am not sure I understand your question or the confusion you're referring to. You still have to specify `@Cacheable` of course but you don't need to provide any cache names.